# Order of convergence of a sum

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0},\;X_0=0$, be a positive stochastic process such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_t^n\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_t^n]<\infty.
\end{align*}
Assume that $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=O(t),\;t\to 0$. Clearly for each fixed $N\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[X_t^n]=O(t).
\end{align*} 
Does we also have the following:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_t^n]=O(t)?
\end{align*}

Comment: Honestly I fail to see how the previous version "For each n∈N, let $(X_t^n)_{t\geq 0},\;X_0^n=0$, be a positive stochastic process" can become the current one, even more so, after an answer was posted.

Comment: I made a mistake in the previous version. There is only one stochastic process involved, $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$, and $X_t^n$ is the $n$-th power of it (rather than $(X_t^n)_{t\geq 0}$ being perhaps independent stochastic processes indexed by $n$).

Comment: I know you made a mistake, and there is no problem with that. The problem is your *behaviour* when you realized this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This is a revised version which addresses the mention (silently added to the question) that the limit to consider is when $t\to0$, not when $t\to\infty$. As regards the other modification, that in contradiction to the original question there would be only one process $(X_t)$, I refuse to address it, for reasons explained in the comments.)*

---

No. Try $\mathbb E[X_t^n]=t\mathbf 1_{nt\leqslant1}$.

Comment: I edited the question, $X_t^n$ is the $n$-th power of a stochastic process $X_t$. But I don't see how your example would work anyway, isn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_t^n]=0$ for small $t$?

Comment: This is just rude, on several counts: first, although your comment suggests otherwise, the mention that $t\to0$, not $t\to\infty$, was **not** in the original version of the question; second, that $X^n_t=(X_t)^n$ **contradicts** the original version of the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that when I stated $X_0=0$, it would imply that I was focusing on the limit when $t\to 0$. I realize now that it is not clear at all. My apologies, I was not trying to be rude.